# How can I add an area/option for a custom page description?

Tags: php, pages, description

I'm wanting to add an area in the Wordpress page editor to display a custom page description in the page headers. Preferably displayed in its won option area similar to the "Page/Post Header Options" below.

[image]

I need to be able to have an area where I can just add a small paragraph or so of text. I know html/css enough to find where to stick the codes in the theme editor, but I don't know the php I'd use to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, easy, and quick way to add your own custom meta box to your *Pages* is by first installing the [Meta Boxes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) plugin (**required**). Next, add the following custom code to your `functions.php` in your child theme:

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'wpse_236870_meta_boxes' );

function wpse_236870_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) { // Add custom meta box in 'Pages'
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title' => __( 'Some Meta Box Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'post_types' => 'page',
        'fields' => array(
            array( // Add custom textbox
                'id'   => 'your_id_here',
                'name' => __( 'Some Title', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'textarea',
            )
        ),
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

As a result, you have your custom meta box.

[image: Custom meta box on Pages]

The authors of the [Meta Boxes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) plugin have a [very extensive documentation](https://metabox.io/docs/) which will help you with anything else.

Comment: How would I then display that information on a page?

Comment: That depends where you are going to display this value. Based on the docs, it would looks something like this: `<?php echo rwmb_meta( $field_id, $args, $post_id ); ?>`. You can [see more of the documentation here](https://metabox.io/docs/get-meta-value/#post-175).

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I'd like to note for anyone else that you need to remember to add a function per the meta boxes' docs. :)